# document.querySelector to handle multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selectors-api

Have following codes in php which activates Optom button when select "p" from drop down but I would like to add more value so activate Optom when .value == "p" or .value == "u", I tried to add (document.querySelector(".motion").value == "p" || document.querySelector(".motion").value == "u") but it doesn't work:

```js
<script>

 function fields_extra(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }

 sell_type();
  // return check_fields();
  function sell_type(){
    var sell_first = '<?php if ($_POST["sell_type"] == 1) echo "selected" ?>';
var sell_second = '<?php if ($_POST["sell_type"] == 2) echo "selected" ?>';
var edding_type_one = 'some codes here';

if (document.querySelector(".motion").value == "p") {
  document.querySelector(".contantable").innerHTML = "<select class='sell_type' name='sell_type'><option value='1' " + sell_first + ">Optom</option></select><br><br>";
  if (document.querySelector(".sell_type").value == "1") {
    document.querySelector(".type_one").innerHTML = edding_type_one;
  }
  document.querySelector(".sell_type").addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (document.querySelector(".sell_type").value == "1") {
      document.querySelector(".type_one").innerHTML = edding_type_one;
    } else {
      document.querySelector(".type_one").innerHTML = "";
    }
  });
}
if (document.querySelector(".motion").value != "p") {
  document.querySelector(".contantable").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this a jQuery to Vanilla JS translation?

Comment: Even if it is it is very poor coding.

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [document.querySelector with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439645/document-queryselector-with-multiple-values)

Comment: Even the original source is awful ... @Joe Please don't translate jQuery (or any code utilizing any  library) like this, it's not translatable. You've to start from the scratch and fit the code to the idea of Vanilla JS and native DOM features from the beginning.

Comment: Let me guess - you checked for either `p` or `u` in that first `if` condition, but left the second part in place as-is? Well then in case it was `u`, you are of course un-doing the manipulation of the `.contantable` element you did in the first one again with the second, because there you are resetting the innerHTML of that element to an empty string, if the selected value was _not_ `p`. That second if on the outermost level should rather have been an else to begin with.

Comment: And please try and tag appropriately in the future. This here has nothing whatsoever to do with `php`. [Tag removed.]

Comment: @04FS: sorry I'm not familiar with this. Regarding "That second if on the outermost level should rather have been an else to begin with" can you put how it should look like in code. Thanks!!

Comment: `if( value=='p' ) { this } if ( value!='p' ) { that }` is a construct that makes rather little sense to begin with, that should have been `if( value=='p' ) { this } else { that }` to begin with. If you made this into `if( value=='p' || value=='u' ) { this } if ( value!='p'  ) { that }` now, then it would still execute `that`, if the value actually was `u`. Had you used `else` in the first place, then that would not happened …

Comment: I added whole code, maybe this will be more make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
document.querySelector(".sell_type").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.querySelector(".type_one").innerHTML = this.value === "1") ? edding_type_one : "";
});

var val = document.querySelector(".motion").value;
document.querySelector(".contantable").innerHTML = ["u", "p"].indexOf(val) === -1 ? "" : "<select class='sell_type' name='sell_type'><option value='1' " + sell_first + ">Optom</option></select><br><br>";
```